# How to know in Android, which connection is using for second not active sim slot - 2G, 3G end etc

Tags: android, networking, cell

For example, I have 2 sim cards inside a device. First slot making data connection. But I neet to understand which connection technology is using for second sim card - 2G, 3G or 4G. This sim card is not connected to internet.

Answer (score 1):

```
val subsInfo1 = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(0)
            val subsInfo2 = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(1)
            val telephonyManager1 = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(subsInfo1.subscriptionId)
            val telephonyManager2 = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(subsInfo2.subscriptionId)
            val networkType1 = telephonyManager1.dataNetworkType //Data type
            val networkType2 = telephonyManager2.voiceNetworkType //Voice type
```

But it's working only for Api 24 and up. Is it possible to get it for API 22 and up?